# Online radio streaming delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On [urbansunsets.com](http://urbansunsets.com/) I am streaming online radio from [radio.co](https://radio.co/). It does work, but after a period of continuous playing, there is a **delay** at the part that shows what is **currently playing**.

The HTML is:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
        <div id="radio_player">
            <div class="default-player">
                 <audio width="320" height="240" controls playsinline id="audio_player">
                    <source src="http://stream.radio.co/sedf8bacc9/listen" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
            </div>

            <div id="audioplayer">
                <button id="pButton" class="pause"></button>
                <div class="live">Live</div>
                <div id="volume_control">
                    <label id="rngVolume_label" for="rngVolume">
                        <i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </label>
                    <input type="range" id="rngVolume" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="0.5">
                </div>
                <div class="current-piece">
                    // Current piece
                    <div class="now-playing">Now playing:</div>
                    <script src="https://public.radio.co/embed/sedf8bacc9/song.js"></script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

In jQuery, I have put together a small script to force reload the script that shoes the current track:

```
function showCurrSong() {
      var currSongScript = document.createElement('script');
      currSongScript.src= 'https://public.radio.co/embed/sedf8bacc9/song.js';
      $('#song_name').html('');
      $('#song_name').append(currSongScript);
      console.log(currSongScript);
   }
   var refreshTime = 1000 * 60 * 3; // minutes
setInterval(function(){showCurrSong()}, refreshTime);
```

Bu that replaces the "frozen" old track name with "Loading...".

Why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: _"Loading..."_ comes because in that script file there is update interval, in which message is shown and then track name comes. As you are replacing the script file it is executed again and shows _"Loading..."_. hope you got the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Loading..." message is part of the code you're getting via `currSongScript.src= 'https://public.radio.co/embed/sedf8bacc9/song.js';` from radio.co.

If you just load that URL into your browser, you'll get something that starts like this (I've cleaned it up for legibility).

```
var radiocoEmbed = { 
   /** * Amount of seconds between each update * @type {number} */ 
   updateInterval: 30, 
   loadingMessage: 'Loading...', 
   defaultMessage: 'No information', 
   radiocoWindow : window, 
   request : 'song', location : 'https://public.radio.co/stations/sedf8bacc9/status', stationId : 'sedf8bacc9', defaultArtwork : 'https://d3r27ctn3zc00o.cloudfront.net/station_logos/sedf8bacc9.20170214030534.png', 
   requestTimeout : 60 * 30, // seconds types: ["history","artwork","dj","status","song"], 
   ...
 };
```

The `loadingMessage` is clearly one of the parameters set for the script you're loading.

Later on in the code you'll see this section:

```
/** * Insert the div on the page */ 
insertDiv : function(){ 
   var node = document.createElement("div"); 
   /** * Loading message */ 
   if(this.request != 'artwork'){ 
      node.innerHTML = this.loadingMessage; 
   } else { 
      node.innerHTML = ''; 
   }
   ...
}
```

This section is actually inserting the div into the page that will receive the player controls, and this is where the loading message is being inserted.

In short; the freshly created `div` element has its `innerHTML` set to *"Loading..."* immediately after the div is created by the code on public.radio.co. It is then updated with the playing song.